# Maven dependency check fails with "Unable to connect to the database"

Tags: maven, owasp

I use the following dependency to check the code for CVE.

```
<groupId>org.owasp</groupId>                   
<artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
<version>1.4.0</version>
```

On my jenkins I randomly get the following exception and my build fails.

```
Caused by: org.owasp.dependencycheck.data.nvdcve.DatabaseException: Unable to connect to the database
at org.owasp.dependencycheck.data.nvdcve.ConnectionFactory.initialize (ConnectionFactory.java:161)
at org.owasp.dependencycheck.Engine.initializeEngine (Engine.java:106)
at org.owasp.dependencycheck.Engine.<init> (Engine.java:86)
at org.owasp.dependencycheck.maven.Engine.<init> (Engine.java:66)
at org.owasp.dependencycheck.maven.BaseDependencyCheckMojo.initializeEngine (BaseDependencyCheckMojo.java:659)
at org.owasp.dependencycheck.maven.CheckMojo.runCheck (CheckMojo.java:72)
at org.owasp.dependencycheck.maven.BaseDependencyCheckMojo.execute (BaseDependencyCheckMojo.java:410)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
...
```

This seems to occur only on a special executor (I use one maven repo per executor). What can this be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somehow the internal h2 database of the `dependency-check-maven` plugin got corrupted. It resides in your local maven repositorium under `org/owasp/dependency-check-data/3.0/dc.h2.db`.

Just deleting it did the trick for me. The next execution will take a while, but after that it's working again.

Comment: Hm, I have the same error after deleting it and restarting `mvn clean install`…

Comment: How long does the next run take? Downloading all the information should take a few minutes and corresponding messages should appear in the log.

Comment: Long enough, it does download them all. I filed https://github.com/jeremylong/DependencyCheck/issues/2262 in the meantime.